# Rust borrowing when adding to a reference?

Tags: rust

I don't understand this one,

why is the compiler error on `let co = 0; co += &1;` cannot borrow `co` as mutable

but errors on `let co = 0; co += 1;` cannot assign twice to immutable variable `co`?

why is co borrowed ?

I expect co to not be borrowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting that the two examples show such different error messages, but not meaningfully interesting since they both error-out on the same basic principle: `co` is not marked as mutable, so you can't mutate it with `+=`.

The latter error message looks more specialized and therefore hopes to be more helpful by directly addressing the problem of assignment. The former error message appears to be the more general "cannot borrow _ as mutable" which applies more widely.

> Why is `co` borrowed? I expect `co` to not be borrowed.

The implementation of `+=` is done through the [`AddAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) trait which needs to accept the left-hand side as a mutable reference in order to mutate it. That is why the borrow happens, but the error of course indicates that a mutable borrow cannot be created since `co` is not mutable.

Comment: but isn't `co +=1` using the AddAssign trait as well? is `co` also borrowed here ?

Comment: Yes, `co` would be borrowed there as well. That is what I was talking about with my first two paragraphs. The differences between the error messages are not meaningful, they just word the same problem in different ways.

Comment: is there maybe a compiler optimization happening in that it becomes `x = x + 1`?

Comment: I doubt that there would be any optimizations happening before you get a compiler error

Comment: Mmm, possible but probably not. Type and borrow checking happen before compiler optimizations are considered. I think it is simply as I mentioned in my answer: the compiler can respond with a more specialized error message based on the code if it thinks its more helpful or more applicable. But it is not clear to me why the error "cannot assign twice" is not picked for the first case.

Comment: @RizalFathoniAji No, `co += 1` does not go through `AddAssign`, integer addition is built-in intrinsic. While `int + &int` is just an impl of `AddAssign`.